# Why store program code in /var/cache?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, tomcat

I have inherited a Java / Tomcat stack, running on Ubuntu. 
It has crashed and I am trying to restart it. The program code seems to be using a config file which I have found on the file system.

The issue is I found this note in the handover:

```
the app code is in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/PCRTiler
config and helping files are in /var/cache/tomcat6/work/PCRTiler
/work/PCRTiler is a symlink for /var/cache/tomcat6/work/PCRTiler
```

There is no tomcat6 directory under /var/cache. I also cannot find a symbolic link in / called work. Would the link be destroyed if the underlying directory was removed?

Is it standard practice to keep program-specific code in /var/cache, and is this directory in any way permanent?

**EDIT**

Found an install.sh script that seems to be copying to /var/cache and /var/lib

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/PCRTiler
rm -rf /var/cache/tomcat6/work/PCRTiler
mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/PCRTiler
mkdir -p /var/cache/tomcat6/work/PCRTiler
cp -r * /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/PCRTiler
cp -r /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/PCRTiler/cache_skel/* /var/cache/tomcat6/work/PCRTiler
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /var/cache/tomcat6/work/PCRTiler
chown -R root:root /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/PCRTiler
service tomcat6 restart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the guidelines of the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html):

> **/var/cache**
>
> Is intended for cached data from applications. Such data is
>   locally generated as a result of time-consuming I/O or calculation.
>   This data can generally be regenerated or be restored. Unlike
>   /var/spool, files here can be deleted without data loss. This data
>   remains valid between invocations of the application and rebooting of
>   the system. *The existence of a separate directory for cached data
>   allows system administrators to set different disk and backup policies
>   from other directories in /var.*

I'd presume that last sentence might provide a justification, although in this case it sounds contra to the primary description: "Such data is locally generated as a result of time-consuming I/O or calculation."

This may just have been an eccentric or ignorant choice by an individual.  It is not unusual to create application specific directories in `/var/cache` and they are persistent, but I think it is a bit unusual to place source or configuration files there.  A more normative place, if you want an out-of-path directory tree for application code, would be `/opt`.

However, it is normal for webservers such as apache to keep some modular application code in a custom subdirectory of `/var`, so that is a precedent.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason not to manually create a directory under /var/cache ... other that what you have just indicated?

Comment: I can't see how it would actually create a problem -- if you can store persistent data there, anything should be safe.  It could just be someone did not want to create a `/var/tomcat6/` and felt `/var/cache/tomcat6` was better.  I've used custom directories in the toplevel of `/var` for application code on various linux systems and never had any issues.  It's perhaps a tedious distinction ("data" vs. "code").